# Detect RTH (Return to Home) in Onboard SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

Is there a way to detect that the drone is returning home (whether due to RTH getting pressed on the RC, or one of the automatic drone recovery states) in the onboard SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to TOPIC_STATUS_DISPLAYMODE and look for MODE_NAVI_GOHOME. Documentation can be found in the [Telemetry API Reference](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-api-reference/group__telem.html#ga563d2333dc43253129a3915970f99cfaa52824a303fb74a40306f0ca4405b8cb9) and the [DisplayMode enum API Reference](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-api-reference/namespaceDJI_1_1OSDK_1_1VehicleStatus_1_1DisplayMode.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a way to see the current command status of the drone, in this [link](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/modules/missionplan/README.html). Although I doubt that is what you are trying to do...I think I need some more info:

1. What drone do you have?
2. What is your goal (in terms of your program)?
3. Do you have an app? If so, what OS is the MSDK on?

Comment: I've looked in the Linux onboard API docs. It doesn't appear to be in TOPIC_RC, or anywhere else it might make sense.